# Python How to Create 4 by 4 Matrices Using text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, split

So I have a "txt" file and I want to create 4 by 4 matrices with it. I need to separate them from each 
"4 4". How can I do it? The "input.txt" file contains this:

```
4 4
55 55 55 56
66 66 66 67
77 77 77 78
88 88 88 89
4 4
1 2 3 4
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
4 4
11 12 13 14
22 24 24 25
33 34 35 36
44 45 46 47
```

Just like I said, I have to make individual matrices and the each matrix ends from "4 4". How can I separate them from there? I tried to use some methods but couldn't do it still. Thank you for spending your time to read this question.I tried this:

```
[i.lower().replace('4 4', '').split() for i in open('input.txt', 'r')]
```

The output is this:

```
[[],
 ['55', '55', '55', '56'],
 ['66', '66', '66', '67'],
 ['77', '77', '77', '78'],
 ['88', '88', '88', '89'],
 [],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 ['2', '2', '2', '2'],
 ['3', '3', '3', '3'],
 [],
 [],
 ['11', '12', '13', '14'],
 ['22', '24', '24', '25'],
 ['33', '34', '35', '36'],
 ['45', '46', '47']]
```

As you can see, it's not the exact thing that I want.

Comment: You should show what you've tried, so that people can use that to guide you, rather than just giving you the answer.

Comment: Also, the fact that, at least in your example, you have a `4 4 4 4` row in your matrix, makes it more difficult to split your text. Is there any case in which you'll get the same separator from matrices than numbers in your matrices?

Comment: @JuanC yes, that's the part where I stuck :(

Comment: @Andrew updated ,thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by removing these lines that bother you:

```
>>> lines = [line for line in text_file.splitlines() if line != "4 4"]
```

Then create matrices with every chunk 4 successive rows:

```
>>> [np.fromstring("\n".join(lines[x:x+4]), sep=" ", dtype=int).reshape(4,4) 
     for x in range(0, len(lines), 4)]
```

Which output is a list of matrices of size (4, 4):

```
[array([[55, 55, 55, 56],
       [66, 66, 66, 67],
       [77, 77, 77, 78],
       [88, 88, 88, 89]]), 

 array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]]), 

 array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [22, 24, 24, 25],
       [33, 34, 35, 36],
       [44, 45, 46, 47]])]
```

Comment: where do I put the file name ? I tried to replace the "text_file" within "text_file.splitlines()" but it gave me an error as `cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (4,4)`

Comment: What if you do `text_file = open("input.txt", "r")` right beforehands?

Comment: `"_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute "splitlines"` gives this as an error :( thank you for helping me out I will try to figure it out ! I'm using Jupyter Notebook btw

Answer (score 2):

Just another example:

```
f = open('untitled.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()

# filter the '4 4' elements, and split on space
s = list(map(str.split, filter(lambda x: x != '4 4', f)))

# turn the list in to a list of matrices
m = [np.array(s[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
```

Comment: Elegant! Splitting on space is indeed cleaner than handling strings in my opinion.

Comment: This works pretty good as well ! Thank you for the great solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit over-the-top but I'm learning, so I'd like to use this question to post a solution using a `Context Manager`. (This means you can use `with`, I'll give an example):

```
import numpy as np

class MyMatrixFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__mode = mode

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__open_file = open(self.__filename, self.__mode)
        self.__deserialise()
        return self.__myMatrixList

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.__open_file.close()

    def __deserialise(self):
        data = self.__open_file.read().splitlines()
        temp = list(map(str.split, filter(lambda x: x != '4 4', data)))
        self.__myMatrixList = [np.array(temp[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(temp), 4)]
```

If you have the above class in your python file, you can open your file types with the following:

```
with MyMatrixFile('test_matrix_file.txt', 'r') as matrix_list:
    # do stuff
```

Where `matrix_list` is your list of `numpy.array` objects. Using it like this just means the code processing the file is pushed in to the class (effectively hidden). Additionally, the file will close once you come out of the `with` indent.

This would be especially useful if you need to process lots of this type of file!